# Cutting a tree, to make a tree stump

Tags: modeling

I made a Tree following a tutorial and I will add the model to Unity3d, but before I do that I want to cut out a Tree stump of the tree.
I have tried out multiple different ways to cut a object but that only works for objects like a panel, cube etc. I know I can just make a cylinder at the bottom of the tree and texture it etc but is there another way?

Comment: Have you tried the Knife Tool? Have you tried a Boolean Modifier? Is the mesh you are cutting UV-mapped? What specifically are the challenges you are facing with this? It doesn't seem like a particularly complex task, but also you haven't really provided us with many details about this tree of yours, so it's hard to know where to begin answering your question.